# mercurial: How to switch to non-rust based hg build

Tags: mercurial

I am working with a mercurial repository and switched from installing hg via one package manager (nix) to another (guix).

Now I get the error message

```
% hg pull
abort: accessing `persistent-nodemap` repository without associated fast implementation.
(check `hg help config.format.use-persistent-nodemap` for details)
```

And cannot interact with the repo anymore. How can I circumvent hg's attempt at trying to use persistent-nodemap. my repo is a few lines of code and I don't need any performance optimisation.

Comment: Could it be that guix installed an older Mercurial version than that you had before?

Comment: @arrowd I fixed it by disabling this extension in `.hg/requires`. It was listed there and I removed the line.

Comment: https://manpages.debian.org/testing/mercurial-common/hgrc.5.en.html#use says that you should do `hg debugupgraderepo --run --config format.use-persistent-nodemap=False --config storage.revlog.persistent-nodemap.slow-path=allow`